# Simplifying probablity equation based on its cumulative distribution function (CDF)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How can I simplify the following probability equation based on cumulative distribution function of X:

```
P(X>a)>b
```

which P is the probability  of X and X has a known probability distribution function and  a & b  are real positive numbers.

Comment: Do you the definition of a CDF?

Comment: Back to the problem: Start with $X$ has cdf $F_X(X \le a) = 1 - P(X > a).$  You can get other, possibly useful, relationships from there. Not sure whether I'd call the 'simplifications'.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(X>a)>b$$

$$-P(X>a)<-b$$
$$1-P(X>a)<1-b$$

$$P(X \le a)<1-b$$

$$F_X(a)<1-b$$